# How can I shrink and center the output size of a pdf image using ImageMagick?

Tags: php, pdf, imagemagick

I am getting a `.gif` image back from the UPS API that I need to build an `8.5x11` pdf image out of (for printing).  I can build a PDF, but it's huge - more like `11x8.5`. How can I shrink the width of the output document?  The `resizeImage` call didn't seem to do it.

```
$base64_string = $accept->PackageResults->LabelImage->GraphicImage;
$imageBlob = base64_decode( $base64_string);
$img = new Imagick();
$img->readImageBlob($imageBlob);
$img->setImageFormat('pdf');
$img->setImagePage(612,792);  // Letter size 
$success = $img->writeImage($label_file);
```

It seems like I can reduce the size with

```
$img->setResolution(216, 216);
```

but then the smaller image appears in the upper left hand edge of the page, which still makes it unusable.  How could I center the image on the page or at least create a 2" left margin?

Is something like

```
$img->borderImage('white', <some_number>, 0);
```

the way to go? (The use case here is that people want to send this image directly to their label printer.)

Comment: I would guess the problem is your pdf does not have a size as it is a vector image. In Imagemagick you can add a density setting before reading in the pdf that effects quality. I wonder if you can do something similar with Imagick?

Comment: If you want to create a PDF from a raster image and improve quality, then use the -density method to change the size, then resize afterwards. `convert -density 288 input -resize WxH output`. Try resizeImage() to your dimensions.